# In C#, How to Get a Control's Name from its Object?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have several buttons on a form, and clicking any of them points to **one** EventHandler method.

When I am in that EventHandler method, I have the sender object which is the Control that raised the event.

How can I get the Control's Name(e.g. "Button1") from the sender object?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cast it to Control and then you will be able to read Name property.

Answer (score 3):

Sender object is type of object, if you want to use any property of sender object you need to type cast it with your desire object,Add this inside the event handler,

```
String name = null;
if(sender is Button)
  name = (sender as Button).Name;
```

Comment: It should be "as Button", capital B since it's a class you're referring to

Comment: @Gabe typo, since am typing from mobile

Answer (score 3):

So let's say you have:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

}
```

Put this in there and you can get it:

```
MessageBox.Show(((Button)sender).Name);
```

What you're doing is casting the sender object to a button and getting the Name property

Also, new to C# language, you can use the safe navigation operator:

```
MessageBox.Show((sender as Button)?.Name);
```